# как остановить Handler? Handler.removeMessages() не отрабатывает

Tags: android, android-handler

есть такой код

```
   public class TimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
      private final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new TimeActivity.UIUpdateHandler(this);
  private final static int MSG_UPDATE_TIME = 0;
    ...
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 fab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
});
stopfab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
});

}
...

  private void updateUITimer() {
            if (timeService.getTime() == null) {
                 mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);

            } else
                timer.setText(timeService.getTime());
        }



 private static class UIUpdateHandler extends Handler {

        private final static int UPDATE_RATE_MS = 1000;
        private final WeakReference<TimeActivity> activity;

        UIUpdateHandler(TimeActivity activity) {

            this.activity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {

            if (MSG_UPDATE_TIME == message.what) {
                activity.get().updateUITimer();
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIME, UPDATE_RATE_MS);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

если нажимаю на fab или stopfab всё работает отлично, но если в updateUITimer приходит null  mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME) не отрабатывает и сообщения дальше поступают, не пойму почему и как остановить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Handler myHandler= new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void  handleMessage(Message msg){        
            switch(msg.what){
                case 0:
                    this.removeMessages(0);
                    messageSendingCodeWhat0();
                 break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: спасибо! помогло